# how to using chaining and check content length

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to use a chaining jquery's functions .

for example I have an `ul` element . 
I want to change background color if content length of that element is 4.

```
<ul>
    <li>eggs</li> //4 length 
    <li>bacon</li> 
    <li>ham</li>
    <li>cheese</li>
    <li>juice</li>
    <li>sausage</li>
</ul>
```

is it possible to use chaining to check content length ?

I know there is a `each()` function. I don't want use it.

```
var li_s = $('li');

li_s
        .???.length == 4 // I don't know how to check element's length
        .css("background","#ddd")
        .end();
```

Comment: Just curious to know why you don't want to use `.each` here?

Comment: To increase my knowledge. `jquery ` is a flexible language. I'm following this language. I'd like to know this flexibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```js
$('li').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().length === 4;
}).addClass('foo')
```

```css
.foo {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>eggs</li> //4 length
    <li>bacon</li>
    <li>ham</li>
    <li>cheese</li>
    <li>juice</li>
    <li>sausage</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `.filter()` at this context,

```
$('li').filter(function(){
  return this.textContent.length > 4
}).css("background","#ddd");
```

This would filter the `li` elements which has the content of length greater than `4`.

Comment: "if _content length_ of that element is 4"

Comment: Oops sorry. I misunderstood the question

Comment: People who downvoted probably saw your wrong answer and left. Hence why editing your answer after the fact is normally going to help.

Comment: @epascarello I believe that they will come back for me :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and check to see what the length of the text is.

```
var li_s = $('li');
li_s.filter( function () {  
    return $(this).text().length===4; 
} ).css("background-color","#ddd");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method like following.

```js
$('ul li').css('background-color', function () {
    if ($(this).text().length == 4) {
        return '#ddd'
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>eggs</li> 
    <li>bacon</li> 
    <li>ham</li>
    <li>cheese</li>
    <li>juice</li>
    <li>sausage</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: "I know there is a each() function. I don't want use it. "